# solution in integers of $ x^2-dy^2 = 1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how do i solve in integers the equation  $x^2-dy^2 = 1 $

i know that i must expand $\sqrt{d}$ into continued fractions

but from this ahead i do not know what more to do

and how about the equation $ x^2 -dy^2 =a $ for integer a ?

of course i have approximately that for different m and n coprimes

$ \sqrt{d} \approx \frac{m}{n} $ but from these m and n which solve the integer equation above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{m_i}{n_i}$ be successive continued fraction approximations for $\sqrt{d}$

Then $(m_i,n_i)$ are solutions of given equation for some $i$. Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be the smallest solution. Then any general solution $(x_n,y_n)$ can be obtained by equating:- 
$$x_n+\sqrt{d}y_n=(x_1+\sqrt{d}y_1)^n$$

A detailed method can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation).

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ and $n$ are convergents of the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d}$, then, as you say $\sqrt{d} \approx m/n.$  Then $d \approx m^2/n^2$ and so $m^2-dn^2\approx 0.$  Since it's *approximately* $0$, but not zero, the values of $m^2-dn^2$ bounce around the small integers. So you grind out some convergents and plug them in until you get $1$ (or $a$.)